# Let $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ and let $A = \{(0,-1), (0,1)\}$ and let $B = A \cup \{(1,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces

> Let $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ and let $A = \{(0,-1), (0,1)\}$ and let $B = A \cup \{(1,0)\}$
>   
>   **A.** Show that quotient spaces $S^1/A$ and $S^1/B$ are non-homeomorphic Hausdorff spaces.
>   
>   **B.** Find closed set $X$ in space $S^1/A$ and continuous transformation $f: X \rightarrow D^2$ on boundary of disk $D^2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 +y^2 \le 1\}$ such that $(S^1/A) \cup_f D^2$ is homotopically equivalent with $S^1$

### My approach

A. 
We know that the topological space $(X, T)$ is a Hausdorff space if for each $x_1 \neq x_2$ where $x_i \in X$ exists $U_j \in T$ such that $x_j \in U_j $ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$

I think that non-homeomorphism can be proved by the fact that $ S ^ 1 / A $ is divided by two points, and $ S ^ 1 / B $ by three, but I don't know how to present it formally or how to prove Hausdorff

B. I don't know how to look for such $ X $. May I ask you for help and how to do something like that?

Comment: For numeral A. If you remove three different points (adequately) of $S^1/B$, your resulting space $C$ is connected. If there is a homeomorphism $f$ between $S^1/B$ and $S^1/A$, it should preserve conectedness, but $f(C)$ is not connected, because if you remove any two different points in $S^1/A$ the resulting space is not connected.

Comment: The Hausdorff property holds for any $x,y\not\in A$ and $x,y\not\in B$ trivially. If $x\in A$,  take $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(x)\neq y\in S^1/A$, where $\pi:S^1\rightarrow S^1/A$ is the map that sends any $x$ to its equivalence class. You can construct two disjoint open sets looking for disjoint open sets in $S^1$ for $x$ and $y$, and mapping them using $\pi$. The same procedure works for $S^1/B.$

Comment: In the first comment I meant that if you remove three, not two different points in $S^1/A$ the resulting space is not connected.

Comment: @Julián In the quotient spaces you only remove one point $[A]$ or $[B]$.

Comment: @PaulFrost The space $(S^1/A)-[A]$ is disconnected, and if you suppose that there is a homeomorphism $f: S^1/A \rightarrow S^1/B$, there are two options: $f([A])=[B]$ or $f([A])\neq [B]$. If you have the first case, both $(S^1/A)-[A]$ and $f((S^1/A)-[A])$ are disconnected and you don't get the contradiction. The reason to remove three points in one of the quotient spaces is to force the contradiction using the conectedness.

Comment: @Julián If you remove $[B]$ from $S^1/B$, you get three components. If you remove a point $p$ from $S^1/A$, you get two components if $p = [A]$ and one component else.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, that is another way to prove the fact that there is no homeomorphism between both sets, but again, my proof forces the contradiction using the conectedness, not the resulting components.

Comment: For B just take one circle out and glue it with the boundary of 2-ball to make it contractible, I have verified this method.